# Can't find a detached head branch where I commited some changes

Tags: git

TL;DR detached my head commited changes but now I can't find that commit.

While working on my webpage project I decided I wanted to revert some changes and go back to a previous commit, didn't know how but a quick search told me all I had to do was basically change branches to the previous desired version, so far so good, I grabbed that version did some changes then decided to commit as I was told I would be able to do, and even decided to `push origin master` to the remote repository, then closed the Bash... Here I noticed that my github did't update, weird, but doing some  research I was able to notice that the problem was I wasent on my `master` branch when I pushed the changes, no problem I decide to `checkout` to the master... and here it updated all my changes back to the latest commit on this brach, wanted to go back to the other branch but it is nowhere to be found, can't even find it wit `gitk --all` on any branches.

Was I clear?, I hope so I would hate to make all the changes over again.
I know now I should have `merged`, but didn't know back then.

Comment: Could check in the reflog for the commit

Comment: wow thanks a lot, I could see the commit id and comments there, just had to change back to that commit and merge from there.

Comment: Glad to hear. Good luck and good day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git reflog is your friend. Find the id of the revision, then force that id on the local master branch and then push it:

```
git reflog # find the id..... once you have it:
git branch -f master the-revision-id
git push origin master
```